# Nested TabularInline model in DjangoAdmin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have 3 models: `FirstEntity`, `SecondEntity` and `ThirdEntity`. I have successfully used an `TubularInline` to include `SecondEntity` in the `FirstEntity` form, but i cannot figure out the best way to include `ThirdEntity` as a part of `SecondEntity`. I assume that this method is a nested inline?

So basically the structure is as following: `FirstEntity <- SecondEntity <- ThirdEntity`

Here are is my sample code:

```
# Models
class FirstEntity(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField()

class SecondEntity(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField()
    firstEntity = models.ForeignKey(FirstEntity)

class ThirdEntity(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField()
    secondEntity = models.ForeignKey(SecondEntity)

# Admin
class SecondEntityInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SecondEntity

class FirstEntityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = (
        SecondEntityInline,
    )
```

As a sidenote i use Django 1.7.2

I could solve this problem by using a ManyToMany field instead, but honestly i have a hard time figuring out whether i should avoid or use M2M fields.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at django-nested-inline

https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nested-inline/0.3.3